# Some question of linear system

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question is simple.

Given a linear system on a nonsingular variety, I wonder the geometrical meaning that  linear system separates tangent vertors.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about what you want? The geometric meaning of this notion is discussed in Hartshorne (Remark II.7.8.2); maybe you could explain what it is you want that isn't contained in that remark.

Comment: Yes, you're alght. For example, In Hartshorne(Proposition III.3.4), I don't understand explaining of proof.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot see any connection between your original question and Hartshorne's Proposition III.3.4.

Comment: Anyway, just to be clear, Remark II.7.8.2 that I mentioned above gives a very explicit geometric interpretation of separating tangent vectors: a linear system separates tangent vectors if, given any point $p$ and any $v \in T_p X$, there is a divisor $D$ in the linear system which passes through $p$ but such that $v$ is not in $T_p D$.